# how to attach an angular modal to a button click

Tags: angular

giving my first go in web app dev, and im using angular. i have a "add-team-member-dialog.component.ts and associated html, css and spec.ts files under src/app. on the main form i have a button that i want to have this modal open so i can get input text from user. How do i get that functionality? below is the main page where the button(s) reside.

```
      </div>
  <div class="buttons">
    <button name="addTeamMembers" type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Add Team Members</button>
    <button name="addRequirements" style="float:right;" class="btn btn-default" onclick="myFunction2()">Add Requirements</button>
    <!-- <button mat-button class="btn btn-default" (click)="myFunction($event)">Basic</button> -->
    <p id="saved"></p>
</div>
```

below is the add-team-member-dialog.component.ts file

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
selector: 'app-add-team-member-dialog',
templateUrl: './add-team-member-dialog.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./add-team-member-dialog.component.css']
})
export class AddTeamMemberDialogComponent implements OnInit {

 constructor() { }

 ngOnInit() {
    }

 }
```

below is the TS file for app.component

```
  import { Component } from '@angular/core';
  import { AddTeamMemberDialogComponent } from './add-team-member-dialog/add-team- 
 member-dialog.component';

 @Component({ 
 selector: 'app-root',
 templateUrl: './app.component.html'
 })
 export class AppComponent { 
 form: any;
 projects: string[];
 submitted: boolean = false;
 teamMemberModal: boolean = false;

  constructor() {
  }

   ngOnInit() {
   this.projects = ['Project 1', 'Project 2'];
  }

   onSubmit(form: any)  {
   this.submitted = true;
   // this.teamMemberModal = false;
   this.form = form;
 }

  onShowModal()  {
  this.submitted = false;
  this.teamMemberModal = true;
  //this.form = form;
  }
}
```

Comment: You're not going to get the whole program solved over here. Explain what you tried and where you failed

Comment: not trying to get the whole program solved,  i created a modal, need a way to call it when button is clicked.  will look at suggested reading from below, thanks

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you're using Angular Material - this resource should get you started: https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/overview

In your Component:

```
  constructor(private dialog: MatDialog) { }

  openTaskDialog() {
    /* 
      Creates your dialog modal
    */
    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(YourDialogComponent);

    /* 
      Handles what happens after the modal dialog is closed
    */
    dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
      if (result) {
        // do something
      }
    });
  }
```

and in the Template:

```
<button mat-stroked-button (click)="openTaskDialog()"> Open me </button>
```

Importantly, you need to create the `YourDialogComponent`. A simple example of that would be:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { MatDialogRef } from '@angular/material/dialog';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-your-task-dialog',
  template: `
    <h2>Insert your name here:</h2>
    <input type="text">
    <button (click)="onClose()">Cancel</button>
  `,
  styleUrls: []
})
export class YourDialogComponent {

  constructor(public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<YourDialogComponent>) { }

  onClose(): void {
    this.dialogRef.close();
  }
}
```

Comment: will digest this info

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to create a modal as a component, then attach it to the main page and add an `ngIf` directive:

```
<app-modal *ngIf="condition"></app-modal>
```

then you have to add a method to toggle to the TypeScript class:

```
toggleModal(e) {return !e}
```

and attach this method to the button.

This method can be reused in similar way to the modal.